# Why am i getting XA resource 'xxxxx': commit for XID 'XID:xxxxx' raised -6: the XA resource did not expect this command in the context

Tags: heuristics, atomikos

I get Heuristic termination of XAResourceTransaction XID:XXXXX with state HEUR_HAZARD then below error

> XA resource 'xxxxx': commit for XID 'XID:xxxxx' raised -6: the XA resource did not expect this command in the context.
>   Caused by ORA-02056:2PC: k2lcom: bad two-phase command number rdonly from coord

Could someone please help me to understand why there is a HEUR_HAZARD at times?
As far as I checked no data loss identified. But worried since no clarity. Please be noted there are no difference in the successful workflow and this

I use below technologies:

```
Spring version : 5.2.3 Release
Hibernate version: 5.4.2.Final
Atomikos : 5.0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen on retrying commit sometimes. You may want to try with TransactionsEssentials 5.0.8.

Comment: This leads to complete rollback of the transactions. Not a retry of commit i think. I got this even with 5.0.8.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. We are running multi node and was using same transaction manager unique name(com.atomikos.icatch.tm_unique_name) and all connecting to same oracle data source. It was same setup with atomikos 3x version where it was not making issues. But here with latest version its a problem since its creating conflicts with transaction ids created by different nodes(same ids from different nodes will be recognised as same by oracle as we use same name) . So fixed  by giving unique transaction manager names for each nodes.